# Model not updating in Angular.js directive for bootstrap-multiselect

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-multiselect

I have the following directive:

```js
app.directive('scMultiselect', [function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element = $(element[0]);

            element.multiselect({
                enableFiltering: true,

                // Replicate the native functionality on the elements so
                // that Angular can handle the changes for us
                onChange: function(optionElement, checked) {
                    optionElement.prop('selected', false);

                    if (checked)
                        optionElement.prop('selected', true);

                    element.change();
                }
            });

            scope.$watch(function () {
                return element[0].length;
            }, function () {
                element.multiselect('rebuild');
            });

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
                element.multiselect('refresh');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And the following element in my partial:

```html
<select
    id="level_teachers"
    class="multiselect col-sm-10"
    multiple="multiple"
    ng-model="level.teachers"
    ng-options="teacher.id as teacher.name for teacher in teachers"
    sc-multiselect>
</select>
```

The bootstrap-multiselect control initializes and displays correctly, however when I select entries in it, my model (`level.teachers`) remains empty.

Answer (score 3):

Had same problem and this worked for me :

First you add ngModel as 4th parameter of link function. Its very useful - more about it here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

Then you basically have to add/delete 'by hand' the option in onChange method to/from your ngModel.

ngModel.$setViewValue() updates the value, ngModel.$render and scope.$apply() are making it visible and spread new model further :)

If you have only single selection then its much easier - less code because of no array control - just use $setViewValue(), $render() and $apply().

```
app.directive('scMultiselect', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            element = $(element[0]);

            element.multiselect({
                enableFiltering: true,
                onChange: function(optionElement, checked) {
                    optionElement.prop('selected', false);

                    var modelValue = ngModel.$modelValue; // current model value - array of selected items
                    var optionText = optionElement[0].text; // text of current option
                    var optionIndex = modelValue.indexOf(optionText); 
                    if (checked) {
                        if ( optionIndex == -1) { // current option value is not in model - add it
                            modelValue.push(optionText)
                        }
                        optionElement.prop('selected', true);
                    } else if ( optionIndex > -1 ) { // if it is - delete it
                        modelValue.splice(optionIndex,1);
                    }

                    ngModel.$setViewValue(modelValue);
                    ngModel.$render();
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });

            scope.$watch(element[0].length, function () {
                element.multiselect('rebuild');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Hope it will work for you too :)

Comment: Very nice! spend hours on this problem!

Comment: And so did I, so I'm glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

IT's probably because Bootstrap components aren't built in a way that allow them to be used by Angularjs.  They don't really have a way to update themselves after you instantiate them, and more importantly they don't participate in Angularjs's update process.  Anyway the good news is someone has taken the initiative to rewrite those bootstrap components in Angularjs so we can use them.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

If you are using Bootstrap 3.x then get the latest.  If you're stuck on 2.3.x v0.8 is the last version that supported 2.3.x

Comment: What I'm using is not as much a Bootstrap component. I guess this is more of an Angular.js question than a Bootstrap question, as it has little to do with Bootstrap.